# Securing trac from anonymous users?

Tags: configuration, permissions, trac, issue-tracking

I have set up trac on my domain for issue tracking.  How to I configure it so that when anonymous users visit the domain, ALL they see is a login form.  Basically I want 2 security levels:

`anonymous` - visitors only have access to a login option

`users` (i.e. everybody else who has logged in) - have access to everything

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove all permissions for the *anonymous* user:

```
trac-admin /path/to/projenv permission remove anonymous '*'
```

For details see the [Trac permission docs](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions.)
Trac offers two different permission groups by default:

- authenticated
- anonymous

The docs describe how to change the group defaults and how you can form new permission sets in the [permission groups section](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions#PermissionGroups).

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by Thomas Zoechling does not work anymore, with trac 1.0.2 one needs to copy the permissions of anonymous user to authenticated manually:

```
trac-admin /path/to/projenv permission list anonymous
#gets: BROWSER_VIEW  CHANGESET_VIEW  FILE_VIEW  LOG_VIEW  MILESTONE_VIEW  REPORT_SQL_VIEW  REPORT_VIEW  ROADMAP_VIEW  SEARCH_VIEW  TICKET_VIEW  TIMELINE_VIEW  WIKI_VIEW
trac-admin /path/to/projenv permission remove anonymous '*'
trac-admin /path/to/projenv permission add authenticated BROWSER_VIEW  CHANGESET_VIEW  FILE_VIEW  LOG_VIEW  MILESTONE_VIEW  REPORT_SQL_VIEW  REPORT_VIEW  ROADMAP_VIEW  SEARCH_VIEW  TICKET_VIEW  TIMELINE_VIEW  WIKI_VIEW
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin). It allows form-based authentication. You also want to remove permissions form anonymous as described in the other post.